# What's happening to my cash?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

Playing a tile on Bloons Monkey City Mobile (on Android) later rounds don't seem to give me as much cash as I expect. Normally you get $1 per pop, but for eg on a tile with 29 rounds I am doing round 27 and popping *hundreds* of bloons, but my cash is only ticking up slowly.

To confirm I started round 29 with $538 and popped at least 12 MOABs, a lot of ceramics, and one ZOMG. I finished with $1099, which seems a lot less than it should be.

Is there some sort of diminishing returns at later rounds? Is it that certain monkeys don't give a reward for popping?

Comment: can't provide enough for an answer, but the "diminishing returns" is often used to prevent otherwise game breaking mechanics. For example, developers might go "yeah no worries $1 a pop", but realise much further in, through testing, that at the higher levels players gain so much more cash, so much faster, that the game becomes a cake walk. There were a few DBZ games on GBA that had this problem.

Comment: But it isnt noticable in other Bloons games. There the rounds just get harder, so you *need* the extra cash to build more towers.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, this has been a mechanic in the Bloons games for a long time, and that is why Banana Farms are really important.

Here is the amount of cash you get per pop :

**Difficulty: Hardcore**

- Wave 1 – 15: $1
- Wave 16 – 22: $0.5
- Wave 23 – 27: $0.2
- Wave 28+: $0.05

**Difficulty: Normal**

- Wave 1 – 11: $1.1
- Wave 12 – 15: $1
- Wave 16 – 22: $0.65
- Wave 23 – 27: $0.2
- Wave 28+: $0.05

More info about BMC in [this post](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/3765/topics/460532?page=1#posts-8809431).